# Counting pairs $(v_i,v_j)$ from $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$, such that $|i-j|>1$

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Given the set $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ of vertices for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, I want to find the total number of couples of vertices $(v_i,v_j)$ such that $|i-j|>1$.

Comment: Don't you mean $\left\lVert v_i - v_j \right\rVert \gt 1$? The expression $\lvert i - j \rvert \gt 1$ means *"where the indexes differ by at least two"*, and it doesn't seem very useful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a sequence of $N$ items $i = 1, 2, \dots, N$, there are
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-2} N-i-1 = \frac{(N-2)(N-1)}{2}$$
unique pairs with at least one element between the two. The sequence for $N = 1, 2, \dots$ is the integer sequence [OEIS A161680](http://oeis.org/A161680): $a(n) = \operatorname{binomial}(n,2)$: number of size-2 subsets of $\lbrace 0, 1, \dots, n \rbrace$ that contain no consecutive integers.